# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" When trying to use Google's Core Reporting API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to make use of Google's Core Reporting API. I got it working with the demo they give you. But now I want to take the code and put it within my own code.

I use AngularJS and PHP mainly. I try it to keep it as basic as possible, the only thing I changed is that I use partial views instead of whole HTML pages.

This is the partial view as I have it right now:

```
<button id="auth-button" hidden>Authorize</button>
<h1>Hello Analytics</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plugins/analytics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js? onload=authorize"></script>
```

This is the demo Google gives to give an idea of how the API works:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello Analytics - A quickstart guide for JavaScript</title>


  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="auth-button" hidden>Authorize</button>

    <h1>Hello Analytics</h1>
    <div id="query-output"></div>

    <!-- <textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea> -->
    <script src="js/analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

It takes a while for the page to load, and when it does, it only shows the text "Hello Analytics". When I inspect the page it gives an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error. With no further information of where exactly the error occured.

Does anybody know what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

That error typically means that you are trying to load a JavaScript program but the server is delivering an HTML document instead.

Check the Network tab in your developer tools. Look at the responses you are getting. Find one that gives you an HTML document when you want a JavaScript program.

It's probably caused by you putting the wrong URL somewhere.

Comment: When I do that I don't see anything unusual to me. Just a bunch of files being loaded with 200 or 304 codes, and all the scripts are being loaded as scripts as well. The only item that might be issue is a postmessageRelay used by Google (which I haven't even ever seen)